# How to deploy Tensorflow TFX pipeline with Git/Jenkins Orchestrating in Apache beam

Tags: tensorflow, github, jenkins, gitlab, apache-beam

I’ve searched google and stack for this solution in pieces and can’t seem to get a foot hold. My main cloud of unknowing is if Apache beam has the ability to ingest a TFX pipeline config file via git/Jenkins and can kickoff via api or cli the pipeline. For some reason I can’t find clear documentation on it. If anyone has documentation that would be great! I’ll continue my search as well. I’m hoping someone has done this before as I am stuck with Jenkins for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins has permission to build/run a Java or Python (or Go) program, it can launch a Beam pipeline.